# EFI format string reference

Tags: printf, uefi, gnu-efi

Could someone please point me to some reference documentation about EFI "printf" format reference?

I mean it's not like regular printf, as it supports `%g` as GUID, and prints a question mark for `%llu`.

My best Google-bet was "efi" "print" "format" reference `%g %s %a %d`, but it did not gave any usable results. Other search terms came up with some color settings of some printers.

What did i do wrong? How can anyone find this info?

Thanks.

Comment: (U)EFI specifies nothing about string formatting, this is a detail of the implementation. It would be useful if you could add a tag for whichever framework you're working in. gnu-efi? edk2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flags are described in the PrintLib.h file.
You can find it here: https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/MdePkg/Include/Library/PrintLib.h.

**EDIT:**

The link above is valid if you use EDK2 for building you programs.
The flags when building with gnu-efi are described in the print.c file.
You can find it here (search for function *_Print*): https://sourceforge.net/p/gnu-efi/code/ci/master/tree/lib/print.c